# Why is 'Broadcast' appearing twice in my notification menu?

Tags: notification-area, gwibber

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and Gwibber/Broadcast has started appearing twice in my notification menu as shown in the attached image:

[image]

On a related note, even with the option to start Gwibber at log is unchecked, Gwibber still starts. I have tried uninstalling Gwibber but when I reinstall it still reverts back to what I see above. When I look at system monitor I can see three instances of gwibber-service running, but I do not know if that is related.

Thanks!

Comment: I have filed a bug report for this problem which might provide more detail for those interested: Bug #916032 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/916032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Broadcast appearing twice in the notification menu the problem seemed to be "unity-lens-gwibber". Uninstalling the gwibber lens removed the second broadcast account. But now Gwibber will not start at login with the box ticked. If that persists then I will add manually to the start-up applications list.